# Hochster-Roberts Theorem reciprocal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, singularity-theory

Given a Cohen-Macaulay ring $R$ over a field of characteristic zero and $G$
a reductive algebraic group acting on $R$, then the ring of ivanriants $R^G$
is also Cohen-Macaulay. This is known as Hochster-Roberts Theorem.
It is also known that if $X=Spec(R)$, has rational singularities, then 
$Y=Spec(R^G)$ has rational singularities too.

I am trying to find a reciprocal of this Theorem.
I mean, If we have a reductive algebraic group $G$ acting on a ring $R$
over a field of characteristic zero and the ring of invariants $R^G$ is Cohen-Macaulay,

1.- Is $R$ Cohen-Macaulay?

2.- Do exists known conditions over $R$ which ensures the above implication to hold?

I am particularly interested in the case when $G$ is a finite group.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in general.

Indeed, there exists $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein rings $S$ with rational singularities such that their canonical covers do not have rational singularities, see for instance *Cyclic covers of rings with rational singularities.* by Anurag K. Singh.  Generally speaking taking Veronese's of graded rings can remove problematic local cohomology that stops rings from being Cohen-Macaulay.

On the other hand, if $S \subseteq R$ is a finite extension of normal rings in characteristic zero. which is etale in codimension $1$ and such that $S$ is log terminal, then $R$ is also log terminal (and hence Cohen-Macaulay).  This is sort of the only statement in this direction that I know.  Of course, requiring $S$ to be log terminal is a lot stronger than simply requiring Cohen-Macaulay, but maybe it holds in your case.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to 1. is no. Let $V:=\mathbb{A}^n$ $(n\geq 2)$. In $V\times V$,  take $X:=V\times \{0\}\cup \{0\}\times V  $ . $\ X$ is stable under the involution $\sigma :(x,y)\mapsto (y,x)$, the map  $(x,y)\mapsto x+y\ $ from 
$X$ to $V$ identifies $X/\sigma $ to $V$, which is of course smooth, but $X$ is not Cohen-Macaulay.